# show mac address on aggregated interface - Junos

Tags: juniper, mac-address, juniper-junos, ieee-802.1ax

I am trying to audit which interfaces are plugged to which switchport on our EX3300 switches. The problem is that when using aggregated interface I see only one mac address.

```
wadmin@SIN11-VCsw-48-11> show interfaces ae13 extensive | find "LACP info"
LACP info:        Role     System             System      Port    Port  Port
                         priority          identifier  priority  number   key
  ge-1/0/11.0    Actor        127  08:b2:58:a1:c2:80       127      40    14
  ge-1/0/11.0  Partner      65535  d4:ae:52:c5:c1:2b       255       1    17
  ge-0/0/11.0    Actor        127  08:b2:58:a1:c2:80       127       9    14
  ge-0/0/11.0  Partner      65535  d4:ae:52:c5:c1:2b       255       2    17
```

This box has mac d4:ae:52:c5:c1:2b and d4:ae:52:c5:c1:2c , so I am trying to figure out how to query which is which without putting down on one of the interfaces for a sec or without any other invasive way
Is there a way to do that so ?

Comment: You might want to try LLDP instead of looking at the MAC addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *MUCH* easier way to do this is via LLDP - this will show you each interface that is part of the LACP bundle and which port it attaches to on the remote switch.

If you don't/can't/won't enable LLDP on both sides, you can trace it out the harder way:

The actor is the local switch, partner is remote - looking at the output you can see that port ge-1/0/11.0 is attached to Partner Port ID 1 and ge-0/0/11.0 is attached to Partner Port ID 0.

If you log into the switch on the far end, run the same command and it will show you the Actor port with ID 0 and 1, which will equate to the interface mappings.

But you *really* want LLDP here, so you can gather all this information only looking at one switch.